# Firebase + JQuery infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, infinite-scroll

I managed to successfully call a function whenever a page is scrolled to its maximum, but I don't know how to make that function call the data from the database and them in the correct order. Here is my current code:

```
function loadMoreData(num) {
  var rawDataRef = db.ref("chat/"+group);
  rawDataRef.on("value", function(data) {
    if (data.hasChildren() == true) {
      var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      var keys = Object.keys(data.val());
      var startAt = keys[num-1];
      var dataRef = db.ref("chat/"+group+"/").startAt(startAt).limitToLast(15);
      dataRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.val();
        var keys = Object.keys(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          var k = keys[i];
          if (data[k].uid == uid) {
            $("#data").prepend('<div class="dataByMe">'+data[k].data+'</div><br><br>');
          } else if (data[k].uid != uid) {
            $("#data").prepend('<div class="dataByOthers">'+data[k].data+'</div><br><br>');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

My code shows the last 25 data when the page is first loaded, and then, when the page is scrolled to the top, I need to load 15 more data before the point where the last 25 data starts, and show them in the order of latest data at the bottom. How exactly do I do this?

Note: The dataByMe and dataByOthers classes are because I need to style them differently.